# How can I avoid being traced?

Tags: hacker-evolution-untold

Every time I try to hack any substantial number of servers, I always find my trace percentage skyrocketing.  I run `deletelogs` on each server after I'm done with it, and when my trace percentage passes 90%, I run `deletelogs` after every further command, and I always make sure to only transfer money is small amounts, but it's not enough.  Commonly I'll find I'm about 30% higher than I'm required to be for my objective.

How can I avoid being traced?